# color in front of image jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wan't to add a color shading to an image-element using jquery. Please disregard the color below, just looking for the effect.

[image: Before jquery addition, after jquery]

This is how I create the image:

```
$(document.createElement
('img'))
.addClass
('question-image')
.attr
('id', 'question-image')
.attr
('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image'])
.attr
('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']))
.insertAfter
('#question');
```

This is what I thought would give me a frontground-color

```
$('div').css('background-color:', 'red').appendTo('#question-image');
```

Comment: Why would a **BACK** ground color provide you with random shading? And why would it functions is a **FORE** ground color ? It clearly states **BACK** ground :-/. other than that: you can't add a *div* to an *img*

Comment: i think you can do it by css. Use background and opacity if you just use for visualization

Comment: Forgot code was all about logic :) I thought I could bring the image to the "background" and use something else in front of it, i.e. a div. I've had troubles before with having images in the foreground and bringing them back, but not the other way around. So foreground color is 'color' property pretty much?

Comment: Just to be different, and supposing you don't need to support IE / maybe ff :B you could also take a peek at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/ / http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: I need it to be supported in all browsers possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in CSS/HTML. You can easily translate it into Jquery, as it would be quite difficult for me to do so in a way that you could easily use unless you post a JSFiddle showing some context.

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="imagesource" />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
div {
    position: relative;
}
div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

What this does is style the the child div to be a red overlay the same size of the image, and position it directly over the image.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crwjLmuq/)</kbd>